# iOS 17 - URL creation from string bug

Tags: ios, swift, url, ios17

I noticed that there is a problem on iOS 17 that didn't occur on iOS 16. I'm trying to open another app which expects to receive a url (I can't change the expected type). However, when I generate the URL, the 2 dots from of the https are eliminated.

Below is an example code very similar to the original:

```
extension URL {
    public var addAppDomainPrefix : URL? {
        let APP_DOMAIN : String = "APPTEST://"
        var finalURL: URL? = URL(string: "\(APP_DOMAIN)\(self.absoluteString)")
        return finalURL
    }
}
```

In this case if my self.absoluteString is "https://www.google.it" I expect this result:
`finalURL -> "APPTEST://https://www.google.it"` 
while instead I get this
`finalURL -> "APPTEST://https//www.google.it"`

Reading on various discussions in iOS 17 the way in which a URL is checked has been changed, however I also tried to use the **encodingInvalidCharacters** parameter but it doesn't work anyway.

Could you help me? Thank you !

Comment: Is this the real code? The non-optional type annotation URL is supposed to raise a compiler error.

Comment: @vadian code edited

Comment: "another app which expects to receive a url" should not expect to receive such a url. "APPTEST://https://www.google.it" has host "https", an empty port indicated by the `:` after "http", and a path of "//www.google.it".

Comment: @Sweeper I agree with you but I didn't develop it, so I can't change it. I hope there is a way to resolve it

Comment: How are you sending this over? Can you just send it as a `String`? Forget about URLs (this *shouldn't* be a URL) and just send `"\(APP_DOMAIN)\(self.absoluteString)"`

Comment: To open an app I have to use the **UIApplication.shared.open** method which requires an URL

Comment: Okay, try opening `APPTEST://https%3A//www.google.it`. Does the other app understand that correctly?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in a URL, a colon is a reserved character and must not appear (unescaped) in either the domain name or in the first segment of the path. See [RFC 3986: Section 3: Syntax Components](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986/).

```
3.  Syntax Components

   The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
   components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
   fragment.

      URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

      hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
                  / path-absolute
                  / path-rootless
                  / path-empty

   The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be
   empty (no characters).  When authority is present, the path must
   either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character.  When
   authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two slash
   characters ("//").  These restrictions result in five different ABNF
   rules for a path (Section 3.3), only one of which will match any
   given URI reference.

   The following are two example URIs and their component parts:

         foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
         \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
          |           |            |            |        |
       scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
          |   _____________________|__
         / \ /                        \
         urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

Apple’s URL implementation conforms to this specification.

So, within these constraints, a few observations:

1. It must be noted that the `APPTEST:` URI really should not have the `//` given that you do not have an “authority”, but rather are just providing a custom scheme with its own payload. Thus, it really should be `APPTEST:…`, not `APPTEST://…`.

   So, theoretically, you can use the following, which preserves the colon:

   ```swift
   extension URL {
       public var addAppDomainPrefix: URL? {
           let APP_DOMAIN = "APPTEST:"
           return URL(string: APP_DOMAIN + absoluteString)
       }
   }
   ```

   That appears to do the job for us here:

   ```swift
   let google = URL(string: "https://www.google.it")!

   if let url = google.addAppDomainPrefix {
       logger.debug("\(url)")                          // APPTEST:https://www.google.it

       UIApplication.shared.open(url) { result in
           logger.debug("open result: \(result)")      // `true`
       }
   }
   ```

   FWIW, Apple’s [Defining a custom URL scheme for your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app/) does not use `//`, either.
2. If you must include the `//` for some reason, then you must conform to RFC 3986 and percent code reserved characters in the authority/host:

   ```swift
   extension URL {
       public var addAppDomainPrefix: URL? {
           let APP_DOMAIN = "APPTEST://"

           var components = URLComponents(string: APP_DOMAIN)
           components?.encodedHost = absoluteString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
           return components?.url
       }
   }
   ```

   And then you can do:

   ```swift
   let google = URL(string: "https://www.google.it")!

   if let url = google.addAppDomainPrefix {
       logger.debug("\(url)")                       // APPTEST://https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.it

       UIApplication.shared.open(url) { result in
           logger.debug("open result: \(result)")   // true
       }
   }
   ```

   IMHO, this is an anti-pattern (building a URL, storing some arbitrary payload as the authority/host), but it might be a work-around in this particular case.

I should note that for both of these approaches, `canOpen` returns `false`, even though `open` works (setting aside the idiosyncracies of the app with which you are attempting to communicate). The `canOpen` must be doing some additional URL validation that is not necessary.

But, I would contend that, while I cannot defend Apple’s decision to simply omit the colon found in an authority/host in iOS 17 (it should either percent-escape it or just return `nil`), their attempt to adhere to RFC 3986 is understandable.

But if that app with which you are interfacing requires the `//`, that violates section 3 of RFC 3986. And if the app is not accepting percent escaping of the `://` in the URL payload, that also is a mistake on their part.

Answer (score 1):

The short version: if you are using `APPTEST:` as the URL scheme, then you can't put `https:` into the hostname, even of a custom URL, where you've defined custom scheme's format.

I've only used `URL` framework sparingly in the last few years, but there is a clear trend of making incremental fixes, that this worked in iOS 16 should not lead to an assumption that this should continue to work in iOS 17.

Having a ":" in a hostname is problematic, doing a DNS lookup on that is not going to work, esp. in the real world.